# Does »über« take dative or accusative when it means »about«?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

> Die Lehrer freuen sich über den Erfolg ihrer Studenten.

What I don't understand about this sentence is, *den Erfolg* is accusative but then why *Studenten* takes *ihrer,* dative? I know that *ihrer* here is a pronoun but why is it not *ihre Studenten,* why not accusative? Is it about *über,* but if so how can I understand which object takes accusative and which one takes dative?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: *ihrer* is in fact **genitive**

Comment: "über" causes "den Erfolg" to be accusative. "Ihrer Studenten" is genitive, because "der Erfolg" is owned by the students. Whose success? Genitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm writing an answer even though the comments essentially already answered this. But it's still listed as unanswered.*

*Über* takes the accusative: *“Freuen sich über wen? – Den Erfolg.”* (Happy about whom or what?)

But that *Erfolg* is further described using a genitive: *“Wessen Erfolg? – Den ihrer Studenten.”* (Whose success?)

You could conceivably say *“Die Lehrer freuen sich über ihre Studenten und deren Erfolg.”* This would be using accusative with both objects. But it has a slightly different meaning, as it implies the teachers being happy about their students by themselves, not only about their success.